# Calculating distance between two points with obstacle using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, distance, pgrouting, linestring

I'm a new user of Postgis, I try to find which point is closer to start_point and end_point.

[image]

for example:

- start_point is `POINT(19.9948526769673, 0.001437951055402)`
- end_point is `POINT(19.996406755300036, 0.003174344782679)`
- Red line is a LineString : `LINESTRING(19.996406755300036, 0.003255738238646, ...)`

I can calculate the distance between start_ points and certain point with:

```sql
SELECT ST_DistanceSphere(
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(19.9948526769673, 0.001437951055402), 4326), 
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(19.996406755300036, 0.003174344782679), 4326)
    )
```

but this ST_DistanceSphere is the direct distance and crosses the room boundaries. (returns Point 3)

I need to return the point so that start_point -> point -> end_point will be shortest (Point 2 on the image), just the approximation is enough for me.

any idea of how I can determine distance between two points with obstacle between them would be helpful

Comment: In a very synthetic way you'd get an approximation with the sum of both distances `[p1 <-> fence_startpoint]` & `[p2 <-> fence_startpoint]` - but a generic, algorithmic way would require a shortes/least-cost path analysis on either a connectivity network model (could be done using *pgRouting*), or a fully raster based approach.

Comment: What if enclosing each room, finding difference between original linestring and the envelope, and then getting the centroid of that particles, and building a network over all points afterwards.

Comment: Thank you @geozelot and Taras for the Comments.
I updated the question, but the idea is the same. 

Approximation with the sum of both distances is a very good idea, but there might be a lot of fences on the way, and one room might have a lot of doors (fence_startpoints)

I am very new in GIS, and to be honest do not understand the other methods you suggested me, can you explain it in a newbie manner? or if you have any docs, or videos about my issue it would be a big help